# Docker Desktop for Windows- Where exactly the volume is present

Tags: docker

I created a volume using Docker Desktop. Where does the volume is located. 
It is not intuitive as it was was the docker toolbox to locate the volume.

```
PS C:\Users\admin> docker volume inspect test                   
[                                                               
    {                                                           
        "CreatedAt": "2020-05-01T10:59:22Z",                    
        "Driver": "local",                                      
        "Labels": {},                                           
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/test/_data",     
        "Name": "test",                                         
        "Options": {},                                          
        "Scope": "local"                                        
    }
```

Where does exactly " /var/lib/docker/volumes/test/" is present ?     I wanted to navigate to the path of it and run some commands for that path.

I referred in many articles, either they are not straightforward,

Comment: Can you explain that further? What do you mean by "navigate to the path"?

Comment: where does it exactly this path present "/var/lib/docker/volumes/test/" . I had an old application which is using this path(named volumes) very heavily. It is not working as expected, I wanted to see what are all the files stored in that path.

Comment: Anything in `/var/lib/docker` you can't access directly on non-Linux hosts, and really shouldn't access directly on native Linux.  Consider using a bind mount instead of a named volume if you actually need to access the data content.

Comment: Bind mounts have limited functionality compared to volumes.